# Extract time on sql gcp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I am extracting the time from timestamp using sql on gcp. The timestamp is

2020-05-10 06:14:25.276 UTC

My code is

```
SELECT 
cast( Request_Timestamp as time) AS Time,
FROM conversation;
```

However, I got the result:
18:08:47.371000

What should I code so I will get the result like:
18:08:47

Thanks

Comment: Try `cast( Request_Timestamp as time(0))`

Comment: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "("

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Request_Timestamp), SECOND) AS Time
FROM `project.dataset.conversation`
```

So when applied to 2020-05-10 06:14:25.276 UTC timestamp - output it

```
Row Time     
1   06:14:25
```